# Dynamic hyperlink database id not showing

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic, hyperlink

Ok so I have a website that shows products from a database listed in a usual format for e-commerce websites, everything is showing up except the image, and the id number won't show up on the dynamic hyperlink that would go to a product page to show all of its information (even though it will show up as text on the page proving its being retrieved).

My problem is that my id number will not appear in the dynamic hyperlink and i've kept rechecking spelling mistakes and my database, etc. and have been trying to find a cure for this for quite a few hours with no luck.

I guess my question here is, can anybody help me out with why the id is not showing in the hyperlink?

**index.php:**

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE catagory='accessories' ORDER BY productId DESC LIMIT 8");

while($column = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<section class='product'>
              <section class='productImg'>
                  <a target='_self' href='fullProductInfo.php?productId='" . $column['productId'] . "'>
                      <img src='images/products/" . $column['productImg'] . "' width='180' height='150' />
                  </a>
              </section>
              <section class='productName'>" . $column['productName'] . "</section>
              <section class='productPrice'>" . $column['productPrice'] . "</section>
          </section>";
}
mysql_close($con);
```

and it should go here but doesn't.

**fullProductInfo.php**

```
$productId=$_GET['productId'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE productId='$productId'");

    echo "<section class='productNameFull'><h2>" . $result['productName'] . "</h2></section>";
    echo "<section class='productImgFull'><img src='images/products/" . $result['productImg'] . "' width='250' height='250' /></section>";
    echo "<section class='productPriceFull'><h1>" . $result['productPrice'] . "</h1></section>";
    echo "<section class='shortDescFull'><strong>Description</strong><br />" . $result['shortDesc'] . "</section>";
    echo "<section class='longDescFull'><strong>Features</strong><br />" . $result['longDesc'] . "</section>";
    echo "<section class='catagoryFull'><strong>Catagory:</strong> " . $result['catagory'] . " > " . $result['subCat'] . "</section>";
    echo "<section class='brandFull'><strong>Brand:</strong> " . $result['brand'] . "</section>";

mysql_close($con);
```

Is this not working because I'm not doing it in a table format, wouldn't have thought so but still, best to ask!

Comment: Do you have values set $result['productId'], $result['productImage']? where is fullPruductInfo.php relative to Index.php?

Comment: Try to `var_dump($column);` before loop to see what array it returns. Field  `productId` can't be null, in that case you'll get general **mysql** error, although syntax is right. `productImg` may have wrong path.

Comment: @AurimasLičkus There are values for each $result in the database, and I do not understand what you mean by fullProductInfo.php relative to index.php; the ecommerce list of products is in index.php that uses a dynamic hyperlink to call the productId and then goes to fullProductInfo.php?productId='ID CALLED FROM DATABASE' to show the full product.

Comment: @grimv01k It comes back NULL, productId isn't null though, every column has information in it!, its auto_increment/primary key and the path is correct, i've checked and rechecked.

Comment: I asked about relative path because maybe path is wrong and it's not reaching fullProductInfo.php or image file.

Comment: I bet that you can run this `sql` query directly from `phpMyAdmin` interface and it will return all fields you need - including `productId`. Right?

Comment: I've got the id to appear on index.php (I didn't notice the extra apostrophe before the id in the link, must be getting tired.) but now nothing is coming through to the next page, in the developer tool in chrome it says:

Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://www.littlepenguindesigns.co.uk/pages/CMX/images/products/". fullProductInfo.php?productId=10:77

Comment: URL http://littlepenguindesigns.co.uk/pages/CMX/images/products/fullProductInfo.php?productId=10:77 Throws ERROR 404

Comment: @davidstrachan As of the moment I'm playing around with it to test parts and see if I can figure this out, but that is the main error i get.

Comment: 404 means that file `fullProductInfo.php` does NOT exist in file path given in URL

Comment: You should ensure that all files exist(Posibly just stubs) in file structure before you start creating dynamic links.

Comment: It does exist, it's in the directory where I want it and all of the links/dynamic links are accurate.